# Is this trophy synchronization normal?

Tags: achievements, ps3, battlefield-3

In my PS3 whenever I starts BF3 (Battlefield 3) the trophies get synchronized.

I don't know if this is an issue or it's just normal, I'm asking this because this never happened with any other game I have played.

Comment: I have the same issue! Do you know if it is right?

Comment: @Ricardo people say that all EA games for PS3 does the same thing so I think it's normal.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're see is the game installing trophy data, it looks like the sync progress bar but if you'll look closely it'll say installing trophy data.

I think EA games have the tendency to install their trophies on every startup, you shouldn't worry about it

Comment: I looked in to it again, it says "Synchronizing Trophy Data"